# change state with error message when error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if the user is exist, it will display all the message like in the attach screenshot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkg2e.png)
else, id the user isn't exist I want it to show in the same display the message :"user isn't exist". it go inside the catch, but then the web crash.

```
...
export default function AllMessages(){
    const [messagesState, setMessagesState] = useState([]);

    const getAllMessages = async () =>{
        let userId = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;
        try{
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/messaging/get-all-messages/" + userId)
            setMessagesState(response.data);
        }
        catch( e ) {
            let userNotFound = {
                error: "user not found"
            }
            setMessagesState(userNotFound);
        }
    }
    ...
    return(
            ...
            <div className="message-item all-messages">
            {messagesState.error ? <h1> messagesState.error </h1>: 
                messagesState.map(message => (
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <Message handleDelete={() => handleDelete(message.id,message.receiver)} from = {message.sender} to = {message.receiver} subject = {message.subject} content = {message.message} date = {message.creationDate}/>
                    </ul>
                ))
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why not use if else?

Comment: where? how? new with this language

Answer (score -1):

if(response.data){ setMessagesState(response.data); } else { let userNotFound = { error: "user not found" } setMessagesState(userNotFound); }